# How to set path for single page application in Hapi js

Tags: javascript, server, routes, hapi.js

I tried this https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/800. This didn't work for me.

```
const start = async () => {

    await server.register(require('inert'));

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/samplespa/{file*}',
        handler: function (request, h) {
            directory :{
                path : './samplespa/'
                listing: true
            }
        }
    });

    server.ext('onPostHandler', (request, reply) => {
        console.log('WORD');
        const response = request.response;
        if (response.isBoom && (response.output.statusCode === 500)  ) {
        return reply.file('./samplemap.html');
        }
        return reply.continue;
    });



    await server.start();

    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
};

start();
```

I want to server the directory samplespa and render the file "index.html" in it and note that index.html is written in Angular 1.X and depends on files in the directory..

Also for the path : http://localhost:8000/samplespa/index.html

I get the following response

```
{
"statusCode": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "An internal server error occurred"
}
```

I get the following error msg in vs code:

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error
Error: handler method did not return a value, a promise, or throw an error
at module.exports.internals.Manager.execute (/Users/pavithran/projects/toilet-tracker/node_modules/hapi/lib/toolkit.js:52:29)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

How to do this??? I have tried everything for the past 2 days and not able to figure it out..

Answer (score 0):

For single file you can use this:

```
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/samplespa/index.html',
        handler: function (request, h) {
            return h.file('./samplespa/index.html');
        }
    });
```

For multiple files, the following. Note that the handler is now not a function but an object.

```
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/samplespa/{file*}',
        handler: {
          directory: {
            path: 'samplespa'
          }
        },
    });
```

Comment: I actually know about this.  But this only renders the base index page but not the other pages linked to the index page

Comment: Edited the reply, please take a look now.